# Trying to populate my spinner with data from Firebase Realtime Database but my spinner is blank

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I am trying to create a spinner that is populated with choices that I have created in my Firebase Realtime Database. However, the spinner keeps showing blank values. All the code compiles correctly and runs, but I think something is wrong with how I am applying the adapter to the spinner. Can anyone see where the problem is with the code?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

private Spinner mLeaseSpinner;

private List<String> areas  = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLeaseSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.LeaseSpinner);
    mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);

    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabaseReference.child("areas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String areaName = areaSnapshot.child("areaName").getValue(String.class);
                areas.add(areaName);
            }
            Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.LeaseSpinner);
            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

}

This is what my database looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please show your code on how you insert your data

Comment: I inserted this data manually so that is why there is no unique key. There are only going to be 7-10 choices on the spinner now but it is going to scale in the future, which is why I wanted the spinner to populate from the database for future state.

Comment: Ive juse edited my answer, Please see below

Comment: First thing is to stop ignoring potential errors raised by `onCancelled`. Its simplest implementation is `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. If that doesn't show anything, place a breakpoint on `for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot...` and run the app in a debugger. Does the breakpoint get hit? If so, what happens when you step through the code from there on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this `mDatabaseReference.child("areas")` that is missing a `child(number)` Like  `mDatabaseReference.child("areas").child(number).addValueEvent`

You can use unique key when inserting instead of numbers so that you can use your query

```
 mDatabaseReference.child("areas").push().setValue(yourValue);
//push means create an unique Key
```

If you want to go to your method you can use this

```
for(int i=0;i<numberChoices;i++){

 mDatabaseReference.child("areas").child(String.valueOf(numberChoices).addValueEvent`
```

}

Comment: sorry if this is a dumb question, but do I have to define 'number' anywhere? or do I actually place a number there like "0" or "1".

Comment: no actually as I have said you can use unique key the `push` instead of "0" and "1". Can you please show your insert method ?

Comment: The way the area names are read look correct to me at first glance. By listening to `areas` they get a single snapshot with all child nodes. By then looping like `for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()`, you'll get an `areaSnapshot` for each child node. And each of those subsequently has a `areaName` property. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Yes it correct, but before accessing the areaName you need to get first he parent the numbers like this `mDatabaseReference.child("areas").child(numbers)`